# Free module or finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

> Could someone help me about the module $K[x,y]/(x^2y^2)$, $K$ is a field. I must to prove if it is a free $K[x]$-module or finitely generated $K[x]$-module or both.

I try find a set of generators but it seems difficult..thanks a lot..

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking - is $K$ a field? an arbitrary ring? are you thinking of $K[x,y]/(x^2 y^2)$ as a module over $K$ or over $K[x,y]$? Clarifying this would help a lot.

Comment: daniel i forgot some details..well K is a field and the module is over K[x]..

Comment: You probably mean to ask if $K[x,y]/(x^2y^2)$ is f.g. as a $K$-algebra, and if it free as a $K[x,y]$-module?????

Comment: @georgeson1960: Please _edit the question_ to add those details.

Comment: No jason... i am askying if it is f.g as a K[x] module or a free K[x] module..

Comment: i did Henning Makholm..thanks..

Answer (score 3):

The $K$-algebra $K[x,y]/(x^2 y^2)$ is *not* a finitely generated $K[x]$-module. Indeed, the powers $\{1,y,y^2,\ldots\}$ cannot be in the $K[x]$-span of any finite set. Also, $K[x,y]/(x^2 y^2)$ is *not* a free $K[x]$-module, because it has torsion elements. For example, the element 
$y^2\in K[x,y]/(x^2 y^2)$ satisfies $x^2\cdot y^2=0$, but $y^2\ne 0$ in $K[x,y]/(x^2 y^2)$ and $x^2\ne 0$ in $K[x]$.

Comment: To be pedantic (I'm sure you realize this, but OP is new to the subject): this uses the fact that $k[x]$ is an integral domain.  When $R$ is not an integral domain, then free $R$-modules do have torsion elements, namely those that arise from the zero-divisors of $R$.

Comment: @Daniel Miller thank you...